# Why can't I use C#9's "with" keyword to create a copy of structs (like with records)

Tags: struct, record, c#-9.0

C# 9 has a new feature. A record type. The record is just a class, but with a bunch of automatically created functions and properties. But basically the idea (as I undstand it) was, a class that behaves like structs, for things like copying, coimparison with Equals, immutibility and so on.

Also with the record type was a new feature with the keyword "with". To create a copy of a record, you can write something like that: `var copy = original with { Property = new_value, };`

Now I wondered, if records were designt to behave like structs (but are classes). Why doesn't the new "with" keyword works also with structs. I mean, as far as I can tell, structs have all features, that are necessary for this feature. Like they are copied by value.

Instead to use similar features for structs, I have to write a copy constructor and can then write: `var copy = new StructType(original) { Property = new_value, };`

Comment: Because records are essentially meant to be immutable classes not immutable structs

Comment: `with` is specifically meant to work with immutable records. It can't be used even with classes. `structs have all features, that are necessary for this feature.` unfortunately, no. Structs aren't immutable, they *always* have a default constructor which means their properties/fields can always be initialized to 0/null/default and have to change afterwards. Classes and records can be referenced by value, structs can't. You have to be very careful to avoid creating struct copies every time you try to access its properties

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can assign the value of a struct to another variable, this exactly the same as a copy constructor. Combined with the "with" keyword would do exactly what you would assume it does. Also structs can be immutable. That is structs can have getters without setters (or getters with init setters). And if I use such struct, the "with" keyword would be very useful.

Comment: Also consider a struct property inside a record. The struct value would be readonly (actuall init-only) and can only be changed in the initializer (even if the struct itself is not immutable). If the struct has no copy-constructor I have to manually set all values. Here a "with"-keyword would first copy the struct, than set the new properties and then call init with the result.

Comment: If it was that easy, the feature would be there already. It isn't. In fact, in structs the default is *mutable* for performance reasons, eg like the ValueTuple. If you want to know the details you should look into the [C# language design repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) which contains the language proposals and design meetings. Check eg the discussion on [record struct primary constructors](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/7cbb29465bb9407638a61b5bf28359909297bb60/meetings/2020/LDM-2020-10-05.md#record-struct-primary-constructor-defaults) : mutable

Comment: The discussion on [record structs in general](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/7cbb29465bb9407638a61b5bf28359909297bb60/meetings/2020/LDM-2020-09-30.md#primary-constructors-and-data-properties) shows that the design isn't cut-and-dried. `A key point in the mutability question for structs is that mutability in a struct type is nowhere near as bad as mutability in a reference type.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

That's how the feature was designed.

**Long answer:**

The compiler creates a synthesized clone method with a reserved name `<Clone>$`, when you use `with` keyword, the compiler calls this clone method, and then modifies whatever properties you want to modify.

structs or classes doesn't have a synthesized clone method. Hence, `with` can't be used with them.

You may want to [write a language proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/new?template=proposal_template.md&title=%5BProposal%5D%3A+%5BFEATURE_NAME%5D) to extend the usage of `with` keyword.

---

**Edit:**

Currently, there is a proposal for allowing `record struct`s. See [Proposal: record structs](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4334) for more information. This is what you may want.

Comment: Well, I actually was more interested in why it is designed that way, but obviously didn't succeed in asking the question accordingly . Anyway, thatnks for the answer.

Comment: The clone method in records is of course only needed to transfer the member values to the new instance. For structs this is of course not needed, because structs copy all values by default. - I think the language proposal  would be useful, because now the syntax is somewhat counter intiuitive.